# Add line to ci.plot

Tags: r, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I've made a confidence interval plot to a simple linear regression problem using ci.plot from the HH library

```
observations2 <- subset(observations, year > 1994 & year < 2049)
model.seaice <- lm(seaice ~ NHtemp, data=observations2)
ci.plot(model.seaice, conf.level=0.95)
```

And it works really well. However, I want to add to the plot. Firstly, I'd like to join the points so I can easily follow their order in time. I tried:

```
plot(observations2[,'NHtemp'], observations2[,'seaice'], add="TRUE", type="b")
```

but it doesn't like it:

```
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "add" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "add" is not a graphical parameter
3: In axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
```

...etc

Any ideas how to add features to a ci.plot?

### UPDATE

I've ended up just running with:

```
model.seaice <- lm(seaice ~ NHtemp, data=observations2)
plot(observations2[,'NHtemp'],observations2[,'seaice'],type="l",
 + xlab=expression(paste(Delta, ~degree~C)), 
 + ylab=expression(min.~~sea~~ice~~(italic(millions~~sqr.~~km))),
 + main="Temperature anomaly and minimum sea ice extent")
 + points(observations2[,'NHtemp'],observations2[,'seaice'],pch=21,
 + col=topo.colors(dim(observations2)[1]),bg=topo.colors(dim(observations2)[1]))
newdata = data.frame(NHtemp=seq(0,2,0.1))
conf.vals <- predict(model.seaice, newdata, interval="prediction")
lines(newdata[,'NHtemp'],conf.vals[,'fit'],col="red")
lines(newdata[,'NHtemp'],conf.vals[,'lwr'],col="red",lty=2)
lines(newdata[,'NHtemp'],conf.vals[,'upr'],col="red",lty=2)
```

The figure looks like this (note the dashed lines are the prediction interval rather than the conf. int. which is what I now realise I actually wanted):
[image: R figure]

What I still can't do is show a legend of the colormap (in Matlab this would be the command: colorbar). The idea is to highlight the slight hysteresis in the data. The color progresses from blue to pink as the years progress from 1995 to 2048.

Anyone know how to show the colorbar?

### SOME DATA

As requested here is a subset of the data to play with:

```
observations2 <- structure(list(year = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009), NHtemp = c(0.314632441576551, 
0.186366426772796, 0.476974553197026, 0.60389558449144, 0.808296103505494, 
0.960909839541133, 0.755078064632368, 0.698608832025563, 0.795763098867946, 
0.929551971074, 0.978281142325487, 1.11821925610747, 1.23718650073483, 
1.19223388599054, 0.966671466003422), SHtemp = c(0.210929776358558, 
0.139817106972881, 0.21783040846463, 0.43431186700407, 0.370475749149358, 
0.255331083239238, 0.385363664392244, 0.403967011006417, 0.473766310099707, 
0.440515909854607, 0.69104778063082, 0.716519830684257, 0.678544576020567, 
0.590446589601271, 0.430452631622458), global = c(0.262781108967546, 
0.163091766872832, 0.347402480830821, 0.519103725747748, 0.589385926327418, 
0.608120461390177, 0.570220864512299, 0.551287921515984, 0.634764704483819, 
0.685033940464296, 0.834664461478146, 0.917369543395855, 0.957865538377691, 
0.891340237795898, 0.698562048812933), seaice = c(-0.79633165604255, 
-0.0484464471858699, -0.821451994832936, -0.761853932432746, 
-1.21404527404276, -1.80462439656434, -2.33021932073994, -1.62220305218969, 
-1.75453917196037, -2.32457807586636, -2.58044546640576, -2.93648428237656, 
-2.24364361423478, -2.63830194428149, -2.53740259589355)), .Names = c("year", 
"NHtemp", "SHtemp", "global", "seaice"), row.names = 137:151, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add a dataset that will show this behavior?

Comment: To add to an existing plot, you do not use `plot` (note that R specifically told you this by pointing out that "add" is not a graphical parameter). Instead, use functions like `points`, `lines`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the problems mentioned above, the plotting of `ci.plot` is done in the Lattice framework (since its help page says a "trellis"-object is returned.) There are three major plotting paradigms in R and the `plot` command given with a numeric vector as its first argument gets you the base-graphics paradigm and this does not integrate easily with the Lattice paradigm.

You could try adding type="b" to the original plot arguments, but I cannot guarantee that will be satisfying, since doing it to the example on the help pages did not seem particularly informative. I did get the effect I was expecting ... which is not an effect I generally seek, but I think is what you asked for. [image]

Comment: Thanks DWin, that worked but I am unable at this point to get to grips with Lattice. I've added what I eventually resorted to in my original post.

Comment: If you want multiple groups on one panel in lattice you would be using the `groups=` parameter. Without the data, I am unable to provide tested code, but this seems to work with a test case: `ci.plot(tmp.lm, groups=tmp$grp, type="b")`